# Where to put compile-time-constant arrays?

Tags: c++, lookup-tables, compile-time-constant

Say I have an array storing the first 10 primes, like this:

```
const int primes[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29};
```

This is all very fine and simple as long as I have 1 .cpp file. However, if I have multiple .cpp files I don't really know where to put this array.

An obvious solution would be this:

```
// primes.h:
extern const int primes[10];

// primes.cpp:
extern const int primes[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29};
```

However, the problem with this is that the primes array is no longer a compile time constant. Say x.cpp wants to do some heavy calculations involving primes[k], with k a compile time constant, it would have to do an actual memory look-up. I don't like that.

So where do I put this array so that:

1. It's only once in the binary (not once per .cpp file)
2. array[SOME_CONSTANT] is also a compile-time constant

### Edit

how about this?

```
inline int prime(int i) {
    static const int primes[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29};
    return primes[i];
}
```

---

**PS:** Even the "obvious solution" above took me quite some time to write. Apparently const variables have internal linking by default, so I had to add "extern" to the primes.cpp file to make it work.

Comment: It seems to me that array members cannot actually be used as compile-time constants, no matter what you do. For that you'll probably need a more advanced metaprogramming type.

Comment: @UncleBens I don't really mean to use it like "int a[b[5]];", where the b[5] really has to be compile-time constant, I just want the compiler to pre-calculate things like like sin(sqrt(b[5]));.

Comment: Your new solution (I assume adapted from one of my suggestions) should work perfectly, as long as you don't need `sizeof (primes)` or a pointer to the whole array.  You could return a `const int&` instead which would let you get a pointer to the array.

Comment: "_so I had to add "extern" to the primes.cpp file to make it work._" Do you not always include x.h in x.cpp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should work (now updated after Migi's testing revealed a flaw):

```
template <bool dummy>
struct primes_lut
{
    static const int values[];
};

template<bool dummy>
const int primes_lut<dummy>::values[] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29 };

static auto& primes = primes_lut<true>::values;
```

[(There is no problem in C++ that cannot be solved by use of more templates.)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering)

Another approach:

```
struct primes_lut { int values[10]; };
inline const primes_lut& primes_lut_provider(void)
{
    static const primes_lut values = { {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29} };
    return values;
}
static const int (&primes)[10] = primes_lut_provider().values;
```

Finally, none of these tricks are necessary with a modern linker than implements constant folding.

Comment: Obviously, pre-C++0x must substitute a nasty type name instead of using `auto`.

Comment: Could you explain why you used partial template specification instead of explicit template instantiation (like this: http://codepad.org/RIDGJPCZ)?

Comment: @Migi: You mean like http://ideone.com/gZT5u ?  Either way could work, by defining the array inside a specialization I prevent making more copies of the array by using other instantiations.

Comment: Yes, getting a "multiple definition of `primes_lut<true>::values'" linker error.

Comment: @Migi: Ok, then you'll have to go the `inline` route.  I guess the special rules for redundant definitions of templates only apply to functions and not data.

Comment: Ok, I've tried it with your explicit template instantiation solution (http://ideone.com/gZT5u), and that one works. I think a full template specification counts as a normal class. I accepted your answer, but perhaps it's best to edit it, for further Google searches.

Comment: @Migi: I just did.  I think the difference is that with this variant, there's a template modifier on the array definition, and the other one didn't have any.

Comment: Update: it definitely works, because if I make 2 headers with different data in them (which caused no linker errors, weird), and A.cpp includes A.h while B.cpp includes B.h, then A.cpp appears to use B.h's values.

Comment: @Migi: ODR violation is one of those errors for which no diagnostic is required... the compiler and linker don't help you find and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use enum inside a header. Enums are guaranteed to be compile time constants and (unless you use C++0X enum class) implicitly convert to integers.

Comment: This is all probably true, but semantically very ugly indeed!

Comment: `enum` works well for defining a collection of symbolic constants, but could you explain how you'd use it to build a lookup table?

Comment: Could you add a reference as to why enums are guaranteed to be compile-time constants?

Comment: @David: "The identiﬁers in an
enumerator-list are declared as constants, and can appear wherever constants are required.", from section `[dcl.enum]` of draft n3225.

Answer (score 0):

```
static const int primes[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29};
```

in a header file. This may lead to a bigger executable (each source file will have its own copy of the array) but I think the same problem applies for the currently accepted answer.